# best way to have achieve complex background layout?

Tags: css, image

Im trying to have a retangle grey background and an "Arrow down" element image below using a single div. See below image.
The 2 dotted lines are the border of a bootstrap container.

What would be the best way to tackle this?[image]
My first thought would be have a wrapper for the rectangle and use a arrow image the width of the container and place it at the bottom of this container. 
Any thoughts on the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use pseudo elements.  Just give them a height and width and then rotate them to meet in the middle.  With enough tweaking you should be able to get them to take up the amount of space to match bootstraps container width.  I can't get consistent results with resizing it, so some testing to make sure it works well for your needs would be a good idea, but if bootstraps container uses media queries to resize and remains fixed otherwise this would work perfectly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  background: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #aaa;
  bottom: -5%;
}
div:before {
  right: 49.2%;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
div:after {
  left: 49.2%;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this creative solution very neat. the only problem is indeed the resizing. It would break and create a gapp in between the 2 rotated retangles. I have played around a little bit with it but havent found a good solution to solve that though. you can see it happen in your example if you just resize the brower width to be smaller.